# VbInLineASM not working

Tags: vb6

I used to include assembly functions in vb6 projects using a [Add-In called VbInLineASM](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=42427&lngWId=1), which uses masm to link the assembly code with the executable (I guess). It worked fine in Windows XP

Now, I am trying to build the same vb6 ide enironment in Windows 7, so I installed masm and VbInLineASM, configured the Add-In, all looks OK, I build the executable, no problem no errors, and the asm functions just do nothing!

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: While reading on [PlanetSourceCode](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=42427&lngWId=1) about this product (wish I'd known sooner about it) one thing stuck out - does not support spaces in long filenames.  Perhaps that might provide a clue?